# Change specific word in file using C unix command or C

Tags: c, file, unix

I have a file that contains:

```
<Ip_Adress> <User_Id> <User_Name>
```

When a user wants to change his name he specifics a new one. That new name should replace the  in the File. I can do it in two ways: by using C code or with a unix command. I don't have any idea about how to do it using unix but I will prefer that solution. I have tried do it by using C but I get a Segmentation error. I will paste the code. (In the function  references the ip address of the user that will change his name)

```
void change_name(char* ip,char* new_name){
    FILE *f1,*f2;
    //Attending to one answer I have changed the var to array but the error persists
    char buffer[30],ip_address[30],user_id[30],user_name[30];
    f1 = fopen ( "data.txt", "r" );
    f2 = fopen ( "temporal.txt", "w");

    if (f1==NULL){
        perror ("Error opening the file data.txt");
        fclose(f1);
    }

    if (f2==NULL){
        perror ("Error opening the file temporal.txt");
        fclose(f2);
    }

    while (feof(f1)==0)
    {
        fscanf(f1,"%s %s %s",ip_address,user_id,user_name);
        if(strcmp(ip,ip_address)==0){
            fprintf(f2,"%s %s %s\n",ip_address,user_id,new_name);
        }else{
            fprintf(f2,"%s %s %s\n",ip_address,user_id,user_name);
        }

    }
    fclose (f1);
    fclose (f2);
    remove(f1);
    rename("temporar.txt","data.txt");
}
```

An example of data.txt would be:

```
100.100.1.31 af9a67fa8 Guest
200.200.1.31 a43fji462 Guest
```

so the problem would be change the specific Guest that matchs with the specific ip given

Example: User with 100.100.1.31 ip address wants to change his name to Superman so the data.txt file will resoult:

```
100.100.1.31 af9a67fa8 Superman
200.200.1.31 a43fji462 Guest
```

That command would work

```
 sed -i 's/\(100.100.1.31 .\{9\} \)Guest/\1Superman/g' data.txt
```

The problem now is to pass it to C with execlp or another command like that.

Comment: btw:  While the answers are giving you a unix solution, as requested, your C-code is extremely wrong.  No memory allocation, bad looping condition, unused variable.

Comment: You're calling `fclose(f1)` and `fclose(f2)` after you just checked that `f1` or `f2` is `NULL`. That means these calls are just calling `fclose(NULL)`.

Comment: @fingerlabs team, Not sure who is throwing downvotes. You have put your research effort. You have provided enough details. The question is quite clear. Keep it up and don't get disappointed by downvotes. +1 from my side.

Comment: @fingerlabsteam, you can call `replace.sh 100.100.1.31 Guest Superman` using excelp. it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your segmentation fault comes from your `char *` that you use in fscanf.
If you malloc them (or declare them as arrays), it would work.

But, I think that the best way to do it is by using `sed`. Please, refer to other answers for commands that works

EDIT: You could use `asprintf()` to simply format your `sed` regex, and use `system()` or any derivate you want to call it (`system()` is the better, it allow you to exec shell commands without forking first).

As I told you in response to your comment, your code doesn't segfaults for me. You could just set `ip_address` to 16 (255.255.255.255 = 16 char) and `user_id` to 9, for a better memory usage.

EDIT2:
Here is your code that I modified to make it work. I added comments to let you know what and why I did it.

```
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                                                                                                   
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                                    

void change_name(char* ip,char* new_name){                                                                                                                            
  FILE *f1,*f2;                                                                                                                                                       
  //Attending to one answer I have changed the var to array but the error persists                                                                                    
  char ip_address[16],user_id[9],user_name[30]; //Better memory managment                                                                                             

  f1 = fopen ( "data.txt", "r" );                                                                                                                                     
  if (f1==NULL){                                                                                                                                                      
    perror ("Error opening data.txt file");                                                                                                                           
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); //If you can't open first file, exit. File isn't openned, so don't close it.                                                                  
  }                                                                                                                                                                   
  f2 = fopen ( "temporal.txt", "w");                                                                                                                                  
  if (f2==NULL){                                                                                                                                                      
    perror ("Error opening temporal.txt file");                                                                                                                       
    fclose(f1); //Close first file, because you openned it                                                                                                            
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); //Then exit                                                                                                                                   
  }                                                                                                                                                                   

  while (fscanf(f1,"%s %s %s",ip_address,user_id,user_name)==3) //fscanf returns the number of args read. If not 3, there is a problem.                               
    {                                                           // Directly verify of fscanf avoids the last line double read problem                                 
      if(strcmp(ip,ip_address)==0){                                                                                                                                   
        fprintf(f2,"%s %s %s\n",ip_address,user_id,new_name);                                                                                                         
      }else{                                                                                                                                                          
        fprintf(f2,"%s %s %s\n",ip_address,user_id,user_name);                                                                                                        
      }                                                                                                                                                               
    }                                                                                                                                                                 
  remove((const char *)f1);                                                                                                                                           
  rename("temporal.txt","data.txt");                                                                                                                                  
  fclose(f1); //Close your files at end, so you will avoid problems when manipulating them                                                                            
  fclose(f2);                                                                                                                                                         
}                                                                                                                                                                     

int     main() // Simple test main                                                                                                                                    
{                                                                                                                                                                     
  change_name("100.100.1.31", "Superman");                                                                                                                            
  return (0);                                                                                                                                                         
}
```

Comment: I have changed the char * variables by using arrays but the error persists, please take a look at my code, I think that I have changed it properly well.

Comment: Your code works for me. Can you please show me how you call your function? If you call `change_name` with unallocated `char *`, it may SegFault.

Comment: First of all, you should verify that you put an argument. If I launch without IP address, there is a segfault

Comment: I have found out the error, it wasn't a change_name function error. I hace recoded all piece by piece and now it works. I will mark your question as the solution because I have to use files instead of unix command, but the other question is right too. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Perfect so ;) have fun coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Unix commandline, using SED:

```
sed -i 's/\(100.100.1.31 .\{9\} \)Guest/\1Superman/g' data.txt
```

That is a regular expression that specifies the IP Address any 9 characters for the UserID, and the Username.

Let's break down that expression:

```
s/           - Substitute Text
\(           - Begin capturing the following text into Param #1
100.100.1.31 - The IP Address you want to match
.\{9\}       - Any character (9 times) for the UserID
\)           - End the capture to Param #1
Guest        - Username you want to match
/            - End the "Search" part, Begin the "Replace" part
\1           - Put Param #1 (IP Address + UserID) here
Superman     - Put the new username here
/g           - Do this Search-Replace *Globally*
```

It gets replaced by the same IP Address and 9 characters, but with the username **Superman** instead of **Guest**.

Comment: And what if we have more than one user with the same old_name?

Comment: Yout command works perfectly. My problem now is to convert it into C lenguaje by using exec commands (execlp,...) I get some errors when I try doing it.